# excel VBA find duplicate entries in worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

My code :

```
For i = 1 To iRowNumber
 If Cells(i, x).Value > 1 Then

     Cells(i, 2).Copy
     Sheets(1).Select
     Cells(1, 1).Value = Now
     Cells(1, 2).Value = "Duplicate"
     Cells(1, 4).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Cells(1, 3).Value = Mid(Cells(1, 4), 5, 4)

 End If
Next i
x=x+1
```

---

Condition :

**sheet(2) > 130916001, 130916001000009, 1 '~> check if 3rd column more than 1**

expected result :

**sheet(1) first row > time , "duplicate", 1600 , 130916001000009**

**sheet(2) 130916001, 130916001000009, 2 '~> change 1 become 2**

result :

**sheet(1) fine**

**sheet(2) 130916001, 130916001000009, not2 '~> error**

If i extract this part of code, the counter works fine

Fyi i have 6 sheets, but dunno because of this or not?

Comment: You have to be more precise about your objects, your code is not very clear what cells it's looking at. Call your cells as follows: `sheets("Sheet1").cells(i,2)`, etc. That way, you don't have to select anything, and it doesn't matter what your active sheet is.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping @nutsch suggestions in mind, here is some code with qualified cells, so there's no confusion about which cells belong to which sheet.  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but should be easy enough to make appropriate changes.

```
Sub copyData()
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, iRowNumber As Long
    For i = 1 To iRowNumber
        If Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) = 1 Then
            With Sheet1
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = Now() 'time
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = "Duplicate"
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Sheet2.Cells(i, 2), 5, 4)
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value
            End With
            Sheet2.Cells(i, 3).Value = 2
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```